# Pentaho: Am not able to write data from Pentaho to BigQuery

Tags: jdbc, google-bigquery, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I am using Starschema's JDBC driver to connect Pentaho to BigQuery. I am able to successfully fetch data from BigQuery into Pentaho. However I am not able to write data from Pentaho into BigQuery. There is an exception thrown while Inserting Rows into BigQuery and it seems that the operation may not be supported. How do I solve this?

Error message:

```
2017/10/30 14:27:43 - Table output 2.0 - ERROR (version 7.1.0.0-12, build 1 from 2017-05-16 17.18.02 by buildguy) : Because of an error, this step can't continue:
2017/10/30 14:27:43 - Table output 2.0 - ERROR (version 7.1.0.0-12, build 1 from 2017-05-16 17.18.02 by buildguy) : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleException: 
2017/10/30 14:27:43 - Table output 2.0 - Error inserting row into table [TableID] with values: [A], [I], [G], [1], [2016-02-18], [11], [2016-02-18-12.00.00.123456], [GG], [CB], [132], [null], [null], [null]
2017/10/30 14:27:43 - Table output 2.0 - 
2017/10/30 14:27:43 - Table output 2.0 - Error inserting/updating row
2017/10/30 14:27:43 - Table output 2.0 - executeUpdate()
2017/10/30 14:27:43 - Table output 2.0 - 
2017/10/30 14:27:43 - Table output 2.0 - 
2017/10/30 14:27:43 - Table output 2.0 -    at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.tableoutput.TableOutput.writeToTable(TableOutput.java:385)
2017/10/30 14:27:43 - Table output 2.0 -    at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.tableoutput.TableOutput.processRow(TableOutput.java:125)
2017/10/30 14:27:43 - Table output 2.0 -    at org.pentaho.di.trans.step.RunThread.run(RunThread.java:62)
2017/10/30 14:27:43 - Table output 2.0 -    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
2017/10/30 14:27:43 - Table output 2.0 - Caused by: org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
2017/10/30 14:27:43 - Table output 2.0 - Error inserting/updating row
2017/10/30 14:27:43 - Table output 2.0 - executeUpdate()
2017/10/30 14:27:43 - Table output 2.0 - 
2017/10/30 14:27:43 - Table output 2.0 -    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.insertRow(Database.java:1321)
2017/10/30 14:27:43 - Table output 2.0 -    at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.tableoutput.TableOutput.writeToTable(TableOutput.java:262)
2017/10/30 14:27:43 - Table output 2.0 -    ... 3 more
2017/10/30 14:27:43 - Table output 2.0 - Caused by: net.starschema.clouddb.jdbc.BQSQLFeatureNotSupportedException: executeUpdate()
2017/10/30 14:27:43 - Table output 2.0 -    at net.starschema.clouddb.jdbc.BQPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(BQPreparedStatement.java:317)
2017/10/30 14:27:43 - Table output 2.0 -    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.insertRow(Database.java:1288)
2017/10/30 14:27:43 - Table output 2.0 -    ... 4 more
2017/10/30 14:27:43 - BigQuery_rwa-tooling - Statement canceled!
2017/10/30 14:27:43 - Simple Read Write from csv to txt - ERROR (version 7.1.0.0-12, build 1 from 2017-05-16 17.18.02 by buildguy) : Something went wrong while trying to stop the transformation: org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
2017/10/30 14:27:43 - Simple Read Write from csv to txt - Error cancelling statement
2017/10/30 14:27:43 - Simple Read Write from csv to txt - cancel()
2017/10/30 14:27:43 - Simple Read Write from csv to txt - ERROR (version 7.1.0.0-12, build 1 from 2017-05-16 17.18.02 by buildguy) : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
2017/10/30 14:27:43 - Simple Read Write from csv to txt - Error cancelling statement
2017/10/30 14:27:43 - Simple Read Write from csv to txt - cancel()
2017/10/30 14:27:43 - Simple Read Write from csv to txt - 
2017/10/30 14:27:43 - Simple Read Write from csv to txt -   at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.cancelStatement(Database.java:750)
2017/10/30 14:27:43 - Simple Read Write from csv to txt -   at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.cancelQuery(Database.java:732)
2017/10/30 14:27:43 - Simple Read Write from csv to txt -   at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.tableinput.TableInput.stopRunning(TableInput.java:299)
2017/10/30 14:27:43 - Simple Read Write from csv to txt -   at org.pentaho.di.trans.Trans.stopAll(Trans.java:1889)
2017/10/30 14:27:43 - Simple Read Write from csv to txt -   at org.pentaho.di.trans.step.BaseStep.stopAll(BaseStep.java:2915)
2017/10/30 14:27:43 - Simple Read Write from csv to txt -   at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.tableoutput.TableOutput.processRow(TableOutput.java:139)
2017/10/30 14:27:43 - Simple Read Write from csv to txt -   at org.pentaho.di.trans.step.RunThread.run(RunThread.java:62)
2017/10/30 14:27:43 - Simple Read Write from csv to txt -   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
2017/10/30 14:27:43 - Simple Read Write from csv to txt - Caused by: net.starschema.clouddb.jdbc.BQSQLFeatureNotSupportedException: cancel()
2017/10/30 14:27:43 - Simple Read Write from csv to txt -   at net.starschema.clouddb.jdbc.BQStatementRoot.cancel(BQStatementRoot.java:113)
2017/10/30 14:27:43 - Simple Read Write from csv to txt -   at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.cancelStatement(Database.java:744)
2017/10/30 14:27:43 - Simple Read Write from csv to txt -   ... 7 more
2017/10/30 14:27:43 - Table output 2.0 - Signaling 'output done' to 0 output rowsets.
2017/10/30 14:27:43 - BigQuery_prID - No commit possible on database connection [BigQuery_prID]
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you may be trying to do this via legacy SQL, which has no support for DML statements (INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE).

Standard SQL does support DML, but these are largely to support bulk table manipulations as opposed to row-oriented insertions; ingesting data via the use of individual DML INSERTs is not recommended.  See the quotas on the [DML reference documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-manipulation-language) for more details.

You're better off using either BigQuery streaming or bulk ingestion via a load job for ingestion, but as these mechanisms are outside of the query language you may need to move beyond using a JDBC driver.